# Convert .xlsx to .csv in asp net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, csv

I need convert the xlsx file to csv file and I have tried this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/246772/Convert-xlsx-xls-to-csv

The project works on ExcelDataReader library.

In local debug F5 with visual studio I don't have error and the conversion is worked, but If launch the aspx page on the server I have this error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Excel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:        

Line 16:         FileStream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
Line 17: 
Line 18:         Excel.IExcelDataReader excelReader = Excel.ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
Line 19:         DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
Line 20:         excelReader.Close();
```

What am I missing?

What's wrong with this code?

Thank you in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    DataSet result = new DataSet();
    string filePath = @"\\...\Tbl.xlsx";

    protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileStream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        Excel.IExcelDataReader excelReader = Excel.ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
        DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
        excelReader.Close();

        result.Tables[0].TableName.ToString();

        string csvData = "";
        int row_no = 0;
        int ind = 0;

        while (row_no < result.Tables[ind].Rows.Count)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Tables[ind].Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                csvData += result.Tables[ind].Rows[row_no][i].ToString() + ",";
            }
            row_no++;
            csvData += "\n";
        }

        string output = @"\\...\target.csv";
        StreamWriter csv = new StreamWriter(@output, false);
        csv.Write(csvData);
        csv.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The assembly(.dll) which contails 'Excel' class is missing in server. Verify it.

Comment: I the folder project I have the folder bin with Excel.dll

Comment: Is MS Office is installed in the server?

Comment: Yes MS Office in installed, 2003 version

Comment: Add the namespace 'using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel'

Answer (score 0):

```
<add key="EXCEL" value="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=&quot;{0}&quot;;Extended Properties=&quot;Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;&quot;" />
```

You may need this entry in your web.config

Answer (score 0):

I guess for using **Excel** object lib. you alredy installed the PIAs. If so, then the refrence will pointing to the **GAC** and not the local path. So in your using statement you need to give the full path(you can see the path thru the property of the added Excel reference in the VS)

Or You can use like
**using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel**

Refer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dd264733.aspx

Comment: I can't install anything on the server

Comment: Have you tried by adding namespace 'using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel'

Comment: Yes, I have this error: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Excel' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Office.Interop' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Why working in local debug????

Answer (score 0):

You have created the virtual directory in IIS for project on the server ?

Answer (score -1):

I don't really know what's the problem and it looks like you're tied since you can't install anything on the server.

I suggest to try to copy all the data in a .txt file and use the find/replace feature (or make a little console program that is going to replace every line of code)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ImportComuni
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int i = 1;
            StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("d:\\comunidatabase.txt");
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("d:\\mysqlcomuni.csv");
            string line = "";
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(i + "," + "\"" + line + "\"," + "\"" + a + "\"");
                i++;                
            }

       }
  }    
}
```

assuming the first line is a and the second is c, your output will be:

1, "a", "a"

2, "c", "c"

now you can copy these values in the INSERT INTO SQL or MySQL statement.

Otherwise create a notepad txt file, add the colons on the top of it:

id, name, country

1, "a", "a"

2, "c", "c"

and so on

now save it as "File.csv"

look at this for more informations about how to import your csv file, or manually insert your data

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/